# Await for a subscription inside a forEach to finish

Tags: angular, api, rxjs

I'm using angular and I need to emit a new event when my for each finishes the post requests for every element.

the elements are users and for each one I need to make a post request to register them on my server.

This is my code:

```
export class CustomerBulkImport {
@Output() customersAdded = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
...
...
registerCustomers(){

  let usersRegistered = this.records.forEach( customer=>{
    customer.owner = this.owner

     this.service.register(this.strategy,customer).subscribe((res:NbAuthResult)=>{

      this.submitted = true;
      if (res.isSuccess()) {
        this.messages = res.getMessages();
        this.tokenStorage.set(this.currentToken)
      } else {
        this.errors = res.getErrors();
      }
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    })
  });


  this.customersAdded.emit(true)
  console.log('emitted')

 }
}
```

As you can see here, my console.log('emitted') is executing before the forEach ends.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of asynchronous nature of observables. you can use forkjoin to hit multiple parallel calls and subscribe to them so that you can know when all have completed.

```
registerCustomers(){
let myCalls = this.records.map((customer) => {
  customer.owner= this.owner;
  return this.service.register(this.strategy, customer).pipe(map(res:NbAuthResult) => {
      this.submitted = true;
      if (res.isSuccess()) {
        this.messages = res.getMessages();
        this.tokenStorage.set(this.currentToken)
      } else {
        this.errors = res.getErrors();
      }
      this.cd.detectChanges();
  }));
});
forkJoin(myCalls).subscribe(() => {
  this.customersAdded.emit(true)
  console.log('emitted')
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, I've also noticed that you used .map instead of .forEach() 
and you returned the service call.

I hope some day I can finally understand when to use .forEach() or when to use .map()

Comment: map will return new array. i collected all the service calls in a array with there mapping logic inside pipe. Since they will only be called when i forkjoin them or subscribe them individually. All the things are in  your control now.